Unable to install ROS 2 Iron
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I trying to install ROS 2 Iron. However, when I execute sudo apt update in my terminal, it shows the following info:
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

And if I execute sudo apt install ros-iron-desktop in my terminal, I got the following error Unable to locate package ros-iron-desktop
I tried reinstalling it but I am unable to install ROS. What can I do?

Or install ROS2 Jazzy Jalisco, its compatible with Ubuntu 24.04
https://docs.ros.org/en/jazzy/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html

The link is pointing to ROS installation on Windows OS. Can you please correct it? Thanks

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!
Please pay attention to the following:

... 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu noble Release' ...

It seems that you are using Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat), not Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. In case of Ubuntu 22.04, it should be jammy (not noble).
Binary packages of ROS 2 Iron are provided officially for Ubuntu 22.04. This is why the ros-iron-desktop package can not be found in Ubuntu 24.04.
Please switch to Ubuntu 22.04.

Make sure that you are using Ubuntu 22.04 (64-bits) not (32-bits)
